# React Native errors with firebase initialization

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm creating a react native app using expo and typescript and trying to create a sign up with firebase. I have one warn and two errors, please give me any ideas how to fix that.

*WARN  [2023-09-07T14:57:25.221Z]  @firebase/auth: Auth (10.3.1):
You are initializing Firebase Auth for React Native without providing
AsyncStorage. Auth state will default to memory persistence and will not
persist between sessions. In order to persist auth state, install the package
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and provide it to
initializeAuth:*

*ERROR  [2023-09-07T14:57:25.254Z]  @firebase/auth: Auth (10.3.1): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition*

*ERROR  Error setting persistence: [Error: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition]*

my firebase.tsx code:

```
import { Platform } from "react-native";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

export const firebaseConfigAndroid = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId:
    "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
};

export const firebaseConfigIOS = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain:
    "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
};

let firebaseInitialized = false;

export const firebaseInitialize = () => {
  if (!firebaseInitialized) {
    const platform = Platform.OS;
    const firebaseConfig =
      platform == "android" ? firebaseConfigAndroid : firebaseConfigIOS;

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebaseInitialized = true;
  }
};
```

My code in SignUp:

```
  const [firebaseInitialized, setFirebaseInitialized] = useState(false);
  const [signupError, setSignupError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const platform = Platform.OS;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!firebaseInitialized) {
      const firebaseConfig =
        platform === "android" ? firebaseConfigAndroid : firebaseConfigIOS;
      const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

      // Get the Firebase auth object
      const auth: Auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

      // Set up persistence with browser session persistence
      setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
        .then(() => {
          setFirebaseInitialized(true);
          console.log("Firebase persistence set up successfully");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error setting persistence:", error);
        });
    }
  }, [firebaseInitialized, platform]);
```